# VBA failing to add attachment to email

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

Not sure why this is failing with a

> "runtime error operation failed"

It seems to be crashing on the ".Attachments.Add fileName" line.  I've read that you can run into issues if you are passing an object to the attachments, but I don't think I've done that.

```
Public Sub DraftEmailWithAttachment(strTo As String, strSubject As String, _
                                    strBody As String, fileName As String)

    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim oEmail As Object

    Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(0)

    With oEmail
        .To = strTo
        .subject = strSubject
        .Attachments.Add fileName
        .display
        .HTMLBody = strBody & oEmail.HTMLBody
    End With

End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub btnEmailActionItems_Click()

    Dim fileName As String
    Dim todayDate As String
    Dim strTo As String
    Dim strSubject As String
    Dim strBody As String
    Dim filter As String

    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim oEmail As Object

    Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(0)

    strTo = Nz(Me.cboUnderwriter.Column(2), "")
    strSubject = Nz(Me.txtNamedInsured.Value, "") & " - " & _
                 Nz(Me.txtSubmissionNumber.Value, "") & " - " & _
                 Nz(Me.txtQuoteNumber.Value, "")

    strBody = "Hello " & Me.cboUnderwriter.Column(3) & ", <br/><br/>"
    todayDate = Format(Date, "MM.DD.YYYY")
    fileName = "C:\Users\crewsj3\Desktop\tmp\Action Items Report -" & _
                strSubject & " " & todayDate & ".pdf\"

    filter = "submission_number=" & Nz(Me.txtSubmissionNumber.Value, "")

    'generate filtered report
    Call ExportFilteredReportToPDF("rptActionItemsForAllPolicies", fileName, filter)

    'generate email
    Call DraftEmailWithAttachment(strTo, strSubject, strBody, fileName)

End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Edit:

It looks like the problem was the trailing slash.  works fine now.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is the value of `filename`?

Comment: Why do you have a backslash on the end of your filename?

Comment: @TimWilliams,  I read somewhere that the attachments object is very particular, and won't work unless you have the trailing slash.  I'll give it a try tomorrow without it, but I think I tried removing it, and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: I’ve never used a trailing slash and I’ve not had any problems with attaching files

Comment: @TimWilliams that fixed it!   Gotta love programming.   Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the attachment can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment. See [Attachments.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add) for more information.

Based on the code listed above you just need to make sure the file path is valid and doesn't contain forbidden symbols. Try to copy the actual file path at runtime and paste it into any windows explorer window. Following that way, you can be sure that a file can be found and read.